# sqlite shared in memory database

Tags: c, sqlite, memory, shared

this is actually bothers me already for a few days. I have a sqlite database (arround 300 megabytes) that I need to reed from really fast. That is the reason why I've decided to use in memory mode in sqlite with backup function. Here is my problem based in this [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#sharedmemdb). Here is mu struggle. When I use URI filename ":memory:" and then [backup](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html).

Everythink si fine I even see in htop that process now has + 300 bytes in memory. So every think is golden.

But because I need to access this database from multiple threads and there for I cannot simply share single pointer to db connection. I want to assign name to my memory database and set it's cache as shared. But when I do that like so:

```
sqlite3_open("file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared", &db);
```

Which is URI file name copied from the documentation. After backup database no longer adds 300MB into ma memory process and file with name **"file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared"** is created on my disk I've also tried **"file::memory:?cache=shared"** but with same results.

I'm on linux Fedora 31 with sqlite 3.30.0

Any ideas, suggestions are hugely welcomed.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using URI filename which is disabled by default for backwards compatibility. You need to enable URI filename, see [doc](https://www.sqlite.org/uri.html) for your options.

One way cloud be simply:

```
sqlite3_open_v2("file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_URI, null);
```